# Swift UITextView size from NavBar to ToolBar?

Tags: swift, layout, constraints

So I'm working on an app but I'm pretty new to Xcode and swift itself, so thats what i have right now [textview color is just to show you its size]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNlKm.png

But this is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3BuC.png

i thought using top and bottom layout guides would help, but I'm totally lost. If anyone could help that'd be amazing! :)

I'm sorry, but i am new to this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to drag the text view between nav bar and tool bar, and then pin its top and bottom edges to nearest neighbors (in this case, nav bar and tool bar), like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wuMd.png

NOTE: make sure its edges are in between bars, not overlapping them. Also uncheck the Constrain to margins -box.

I got it to look like this very quickly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIzVw.png

There are many other ways to do this, and this is just one of them. Search for storyboards tutorials and you'll find many good tutorials how to use Interface Builder. :)

Comment: thank you so much, simple answer, yet helped solve my problem in seconds. thank you alkku!